# ServerVersion throws 'System.InvalidOperationException' when trying to connect to local database in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, database-connection, adventureworks

I'm trying to exercise the ADO.net framework, and I'm in the very beginning. I'm trying to connect to my local database using the following string:

```
connectionString="Server=localhost;Database=AdventureWorks2012; Integrated Security=True;"
```

But when I try to use a button I created to access the database, I get [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vczRv.png)

The interesting part is that before I use the button, everything is all right, as I saw through debugging and breaking right after

```
conn.Open();
```

(ServerVersion doesn't throw an exception yet, instead it returns the version "11.00.3153" )

With the exception of the connection string, I'm really pretty sure the code is correct, so I think the problem is configuration related. Any ideas?

The event for when the code breaks is:

```
private void buttonGetEmployee_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            DataLayer.Employees es = new DataLayer.Employees();
            DataLayer.Employee employee = es.GetEmployee(int.Parse(textBoxEID.Text));

            textBoxFName.Text = employee.FirstName;
            textBoxLName.Text = employee.LastName;
            textBoxDName.Text = employee.DepartmentName;

        }
        catch { }
```

Comment: Post the relevant code *in your question* along with the error message. Outside links break, and the point of SO is to create a repository of knowledge that is useful to both you and future users, regardless of if the links you post break.

Comment: @eddie_cat , okay, done.

Comment: That's not a bad error - it just means that as long as you're not connected to the server, the `ServerVersion` cannot be determined ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just discovered the problem. In

```
public class Employees{...}
```

the associated command

```
cmd.CommandText = @"MyQuery";
```

was badly defined, not containing the expected properties, and because of that it returned the wrong object for the event showed in the question, the

```
buttonGetEmployee_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

This lead to the error you saw, which may seem related to ServerVersion but indicated in fact an error occuring when the event was called to use the object

```
Employees es
```